# How to stop video when Collection View cell is offscreen using MMPlayerView

Tags: swift, xcode

So i am trying to build a instagram replica for a collage project and having issues with the videos in the feed.

I am using the framework MMPlayerView : https://github.com/MillmanY/MMPlayerView

I have added a collection view and another collection view inside that for the images and the player view.

```
mmPlayerLayer.playView = cell.imgView
mmPlayerLayer.getStatusBlock { [weak self] (status) in

}
self.mmPlayerLayer.set(url: DemoSource.shared.demoData[indexPath.row].play_Url)
self.mmPlayerLayer.resume()
```

This is the code i am using, in my cell.

the feed shows the images and video but carry's on playing the video after i scroll past it, i want the video to stop playing once the cell is not visible but been stuck on this for a few days.

Comment: I have answer on this issue. Please refer this issue on GitHub:- https://github.com/MillmanY/MMPlayerView/issues/70

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your logic to stop the player in the following method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.mmPlayerLayer.player.pause()
    }
```

this method will be called whenever a cell was removed from the table.